# Obter valores de uma tabela que não estejam contidos em outra

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, join

Gostaria de saber como posso obter valores de um banco mysql sendo que, os dados obtidos devem estar em uma tabela e não estar em outra.

Por exemplo: quero todos os equipamentos (tabela equipamentos) que não esta reservados (tabela reservas)

Comment: Você quer pegar valores que estão em mais de uma tabela?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Você não dá muita informação mas se percebi bem isto deve fazer o que pretende:

```
SELECT * FROM equipamentos e
WHERE e.id NOT IN (SELECT equipamentoId FROM reservas);
```

Parto do principio que na tabela reservas tem o id do equipamento que está reservado.

Veja a funcionar no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26be7/1)

Outra forma de fazer o mesmo:

```
SELECT * FROM equipamentos e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM reservas r WHERE e.id = r.equipamentoId);
```

Veja a funcionar no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26be7/4)

**Uma pequena explicação:**

Um SELECT só retorna as linhas que tornam a cláusula *WHERE* verdadeira.

No primeiro exemplo cada *id do equipamento* é verificado se não está (*NOT IN*) na lista retornada pela *sub-query* `SELECT equipamentoId FROM reservas`.
Se não estiver, a cláusula *WHERE* é verdadeira e o *SELECT* retorna essa linha.

No segundo exemplo cada *id do equipamento* é verificado se não existe (*NOT EXISTS*) na tabela *reservas*.
*NOT EXISTS* é *true* se a *sub-query* `SELECT * FROM reservas r WHERE e.id = r.equipamentoId` não retornar linhas, a cláusula *WHERE* é verdadeira e o *SELECT* retorna essa linha.

Answer (score 4):

Outra forma de obter estas informações é através do LEFT JOIN ou RIGHT JOIN
Observe:

Tabela A contém os campos a,b,c
Tabela B contem os campos a,b,c,d,e,f

```
SELECT A.a, A.b, A.c, B.d, B.e, B.f
  FROM A
 RIGHT JOIN B ON A.a = B.a AND A.b = B.b AND A.c = B.c
 WHERE B.d IS NULL OR B.e IS NULL
```

Repare que diferente do critério IN que foi utilizado na resposta anterior este método aceita mais campos no critério WHERE

Este método é muito costumeiro quando tentamos comparar duas ou mais tabelas que possuem informações semelhantes