# como consultar dados em uma tabela que não estejam relacionados à outra tabela?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, join

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categoria` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `descricao` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `veiculo` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `modelo` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `placa` VARCHAR(7) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `cat_id` (`cat_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `cat_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`cat_id`)
    REFERENCES `categoria` (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `locacao` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `veiculo_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `dt_inicio` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `dt_fim` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `veiculo_id` (`veiculo_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `veiculo_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`veiculo_id`)
    REFERENCES `veiculo` (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Eu gostaria de consultar todas as categorias e a contagem de cada veículo em cada .. daí eu construi essa consulta:

```
SELECT c.nome, count(c.id) AS disponiveis
FROM categoria AS c
INNER JOIN veiculo AS v
ON v.cat_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id;
```

que me retorna isso:

```
nome, disponiveis
A - ECONÔMICO, 5
B - ECONÔMICO COM AR, 4
C - SEDAN COM AR, 2
```

Daí eu preciso agora que a coluna **disponiveis** me retorne apenas os veículos que não estão ou estarão locados em um período **> dt_inicio e < dt_fim**, porém não consegui.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz de por onde seguir?

---

Eu tentei [isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57538/obter-valores-de-uma-tabela-que-n%C3%A3o-estejam-contidos-em-outra) mas não saiu como esperado. Continuou retornando todos os veículos, até os que estarão locados em um período X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para retornar os veículos disponíveis você utiliza a `query`:

```
SELECT v.*
  FROM veiculo v
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT l.id
                    FROM locacao l
                   WHERE l.veiculo_id = v.veiculo_id
                     AND '2016-11-22' BETWEEN l.dt_inicio AND l.dt_fim)
```

Logo aplicando para categoria temos:

```
SELECT c.nome,
       (SELECT count(v.id)
          FROM veiculo AS v
         WHERE v.cat_id = c.id
           AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT l.id
                            FROM locacao AS l
                           WHERE l.veiculo_id = v.veiculo_id
                             AND '2016-11-22' BETWEEN l.dt_inicio AND l.dt_fim)) AS disponiveis
  FROM categoria AS c
```

Ou

```
SELECT c.nome,
       count(c.id) AS disponiveis
  FROM categoria AS c
       LEFT JOIN veiculo AS v ON v.cat_id = c.id
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT l.id
                    FROM locacao l
                   WHERE l.veiculo_id = v.veiculo_id
                     AND '2016-11-22' BETWEEN l.dt_inicio AND l.dt_fim)
```

Comment: Resolveu até meu problema de pesquisar os veículos de uma categoria que não estejam locados. Só adicionei no WHERE da primeira consulta o AND cat_id = 1 LIMIT 1. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar as clausulas [BETWEEN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) e [EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) para verificar se na tabela locacao existem dados com o que você precisa.

```
SELECT c.nome, count(c.id) AS disponiveis
    FROM categoria AS c
    INNER JOIN veiculo AS v
    ON v.cat_id = c.id
    where exists (select 1 from locacao l
    where suadata BETWEEN l.dt_inicio and l.dt_fim
    and l.veiculo_id = v.id)
    GROUP BY c.id;
```

> Detalhe; os veículos que não estão ou estarão locados em um período

Para os não locados use not exists e para os que estarão somente exists